# Issue with German accented characters displaying in HTML5 page

Tags: html, browser

I have a HTML5 webpage.

The following sentence and others that contain german characters are not displaying properly: Wie viel Support und Wartung wird monatlich benötigt, um sie zu aktualisieren und zu ergänzen?

I have tried adding this to the top of the php file:

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); ?>
```

I also have `<meta charset="utf-8">` at the top of the HTML.

I have said the file using UTF-8 (CPanel file manager) and I have also tried adding AddDefaultCharset Off to .htaccess

All these solutions that have worked for others do not work in this case.

Comment: How was the original text created? I hope it wasn't MS Word.

Comment: Yes it was, but I have even tried replacing the accented characters with the HTML equivalents for example &auml;  It still displays incorrectly. Even if I edit the website in Google chrome using the browser tool.

Comment: Some years ago I had that problem, it was encoding on the database. In your case, since you are getting strings from word, try to copy paste from word to note pad, then deselect, reselect copy and paste in your php file.

Comment: also, there is a jquery function to 'clean' ms word, you can find it here https://gist.github.com/sbrin/6801034